# How to share Remote URL(https://...) using UIDocumentInteractionController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, share, uidocumentinteraction

I want to share remote URL using `UIDocumentInteractionController` from my app. How will I do this?

Here is my code:

```
let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init()
documentInteractionController.name = dataUrl
documentInteractionController.delegate = self
documentInteractionController.uti = "public.content"
documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

Comment: what kind of content is on the remote server?  a single file or an entire webpage (graphics + video + text)?

Comment: this url will be used for Deep-linking , when this link will open by deep-linking , by using access-token data is return which is in json.